# How do I solve this inequality $\frac{c-1}{\sqrt{c}}<2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this inequality $\frac{c-1}{\sqrt{c}}<2$?

Wolfram Alpha says  that it is $0<c<3+2\sqrt{2}$ but my brain is just not letting me see how to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for $\sqrt{c}$ to be real, we need $c\ge 0,$ and we clearly can't allow $c=0,$ since then $\frac{c-1}{\sqrt{c}}$ is undefined. Hence, we necessarily must have $c>0.$ Multiplying both sides of the given inequality by the positive value $\sqrt{c}$ then gives us the equivalent inequality $$c-1<2\sqrt{c}.$$ Note that this is the same as $$\left(\sqrt{c}\right)^2-1<2\sqrt{c},$$ and some rearrangement gives us $$\left(\sqrt c\right)^2-2\sqrt{c}-1<0.$$ Adding $2$ to both sides gives us $$\left(\sqrt c\right)^2-2\sqrt{c}+1<2,$$ which is the same as $$\left(\sqrt c-1\right)^2<2.$$ Hence, we have $$\left|\sqrt c-1\right|<\sqrt2,$$ which yields $$1-\sqrt2<\sqrt c<1+\sqrt2.$$ Since we already know $\sqrt c>0,$ then this becomes $$0<\sqrt{c}<1+\sqrt2,$$ whence squaring yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to solve the inequality $(c-1)<2\sqrt c$ by squaring both sides: You would get a quadratic- and you have to know when is a quatratic $\geq 0$.

Comment: Squaring both sides of an  inequality need not preserve the inequality, unless on one knows that both sides of the inequality are positive. For example, $c=\frac19$ is a solution to the given inequality, but ***not*** to the inequality $(c-1)^2<4c.$

Comment: @CameronBuie: It's supposed to be a hint- and not a complete answer. This hint is great to get started- and then one must think about "extraneous solutions" that come up while squaring. For easy hw questions I generally don't give the full solution -unless aked specifically.

But of course- a bounty hunter like you can hardly appreciate the difference.

Comment: I've no problem with valid hints--many of my answers are in that vein. "Hints" that mislead, however, I will not allow to pass unremarked upon. (Full disclosure: I just deleted one of my own "hints" that turned out to be useless.) My purpose on this site is to educate people--whether that be the OP, myself, or a well-meaning but incorrect answerer. Your answer didn't introduce a few extraneous solutions. Rather, you *and every other answerer* (thus far) hinted at/gave a solution that *eliminated uncountably-many actual solutions.* Label me a "bounty hunter" if you wish, but fix your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need $c>0$ for $\sqrt{c}$ to exist.

Then you study the other condition by solving the equality case.

$c-1=2\sqrt{c}$, that is $c^2-6c+1=0$.

You can probably finish from here...

Comment: Not exactly. $\sqrt0$ exists.

Comment: @CameronBuie You are right, I wrote quicker than my thoughts. In fact you need $c>0$ for $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$ to exist...

Answer (score 0):

Solve the equation $\frac{c-1}{\sqrt c}=2$ by

$\frac{c-1}{\sqrt c}=2$ implies $c-1=2\sqrt c$

Squaring both parts will give you: $c^2-2c+1=4c$, equivalent to $c^2-6c+1=0$, which you can solve. It gives you the correct answers after combining it with the fact that $c$ must be $\geq 0$ for $\sqrt{c}$ to exist (in the reals)

Comment: Solving this quadratic gives the boundary points for the solution set of $(c-1)^2<4c,$ but this is not equivalent. Squaring both sides of an inequality need not preserve the inequality, unless on one knows that both sides of the inequality are positive. For example, $c=\frac19$ is a solution to the given inequality, but ***not*** to the inequality $(c-1)^2<4c.$

Comment: You're absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

$$c-1<2\sqrt{c}\Rightarrow (c-1)^2<4c\Rightarrow c^2-2c+1<4c\Rightarrow c^2-6c+1<0$$
This is the same as 
$$c^2-2\cdot3\cdot c+9-8<0\Rightarrow (c-3)^2-(2\sqrt{2})^2<0\Rightarrow (c-3-2\sqrt{2})(c-3+2\sqrt{2})<0$$
We have $$0<3-2\sqrt{2}<c<3+2\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Squaring both sides of an  inequality need not preserve the inequality, unless on one knows that both sides of the inequality are positive. For example, $c=\frac19$ is a solution to the given inequality, but ***not*** to the inequality $(c-1)^2<4c.$  This is because $\frac19<3-2\sqrt2.$

Comment: @CameronBuie: Yes you are right.